# Changing local clock affects remote SQL Server database functionality

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm having an issue with some SQL Server 2008 queries and I think I got it down to differences between the server and the local application. Here's a basic description of my scenario:

I'm using a local application that performs insert statements on a remote database. Everything works fine until I change the clock on the local machine that runs the application (let's say a couple days in the future), since the data doesn't really get inserted on the remote database (or at least, I can't see it).

My question is, to what extent is SQL Server functionality affected by this kind of changes? In my example, do the insertions not get completed due to integrity matters?

Comment: If the INSERT statements included date/time from the client application, then changes to the workstations datetime settings will be apparent in the records.  This is why you don't code your applications to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that is affected for sure by time difference is NTLM/Kerberos handshake, as well as SSL, all of which tolerate usually 30 minutes time drift between participants. If you change your clock *days* forward, you won't be able to successfully open a connection with SQL Server in most cases. I must assume your application is also likely swallowing the connect error silently.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the local application is affected. It's not SQL Server. SQL Server would certainly only be using the time on the remote machine.

Comment: Doesn't it have hidden timestamps of some sort for every record processed?

Comment: I don't know if I'd call them hidden, but it does know when transactions occur. They would be useless if they were timestamps from the client, though, because there would be no guarantee that they were consistent. Timestamps are generated on the server.

Comment: And it doesn't rely on datetime it uses sequence numbers.